# Java, Getting a weird Socket Exception: "Broken pipe" and "Operation timed out"

Tags: java, sockets, exception, tcp

I have a client server application that has 16 threads (8 client, 8 server) and each has a TCP connection in a 1-1 matching (so 8 TCP streams).

I have the server sending X amount of random bytes then close. Meanwhile the client just reads X amount of data then closes.  X is predetermined.  I am also using dummynet for bandwidth throttling but I am leaving the pipe with plenty of bandwidth (100Mbps). Sometimes it works fine, other times I get these exceptions.  I am transferring 1GB spread evenly over all 8 connections in around 3.5 minutes.

The client is throwing this exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at miccbull.parralleltcp.client.StreamWorker.run(StreamWorker.java:43)
```

The server is throwing this exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:124)
at miccbull.parralleltcp.server.TransmissionWorker.run(TransmissionWorker.java:51)
```

Server Code:

```
public void run() {

    OutputStream os = null;

    try {
        socket = sSocket.accept();
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    //send the data
    for(int i = 0; i < Server.TRANSMISSIONS; i++){
        System.out.println(sSocket.getLocalPort() + " sending set " + (i+1) + " of " + Server.TRANSMISSIONS);

        try {
            os.write(new byte[Server.FILE_SIZE/Server.numStreams/Server.TRANSMISSIONS]);
            os.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Closing server (at write bytes) with socket id: " + sSocket.getLocalPort());
        } 
    }

    System.out.println("Worker " + sSocket.getLocalPort() + " done");

    //close the socket
    try {
        socket.close();
        sSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Client Code:

```
    public void run(){

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];  //number of bytes to read per client stream
    InputStream is = null;

    //connect to server
    try {
        connectionSocket = new Socket("localhost", id);
        is = connectionSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //read file from server
    int value = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    try {

        while(bytesRead < (Client.FILE_SIZE/Client.NUM_STREAMS)){
            value = is.read(bytes, 0, 1024);
            if(value == -1){
                System.out.println("******************************** Read is -1 for client " + id);
            }
            else if(value == 0){
                System.out.println("******************************** Read is 0 for client " + id);
            }
            bytesRead += value;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("**** Exception in read in client " + id + " and value value was: " + value);
        if(bytesRead == (Client.FILE_SIZE/Client.NUM_STREAMS)){
            System.out.println("************ NOT ACTUALLY BAD" + id);
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Finished download
    Client.workerDone();
    System.out.println("Worker " + id + " done received " + bytesRead);
```

What causes these exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Your client never stops reading because you don't test for read() returning < 0.

Comment: Hi, I stop reading when I have received all the bytes I am expecting from the server, specifically with this condition `bytesRead < (Client.FILE_SIZE/Client.NUM_STREAMS)`. Nonetheless, I threw some checks in there of the value returned from read() and it is never < 0 during my experiment. Which might be cause for concern??

Comment: This is getting very frustrating. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Michael nevertheless your code is wrong. What if the server disconnects before sending all the data you're expecting? Your code won't detect that and will loop forever.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I see in your code:

1. I have verified that every call to both `socket.getOutputStream()` and `socket.getInputStream()` returns a *different* stream associated with the socket.  You should call them each once per socket and put the result in a local variable.

   ```
   OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
   // send the data
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       ....
       outputStream.write(...);
   ```
2. There are a number of places where you should return from your `run()` method but I suspect you knew that.
3. You are not checking the return value from `read()` to see if it returns -1 on EOF.  You should not just make the assumption you are getting the correct number of bytes.
4. I assume you are writing blocks of null characters for a reason.

Comment: 1. "I have verified that every call to both socket.getOutputStream() and socket.getInputStream() returns a different stream associated with the socket." I have just verified the opposite from the source code. So ultimately that isn't his problem at all. 1.1. Flushing such a stream does nothing.

Comment: @Gray Hi, I thought the streams were the same but I put them into local variables as you suggested and I have checked the values from read(). I just ran the test and got a BrokenPipe exception at the client with a most recent read value of 162. 

I am sending random bytes because this application is just for performance testing.

Can you see anything else that might be suspect?

Comment: @EJP, huh, I don't have access to the JDK source on my Mac (grumble), but the objects have different `toString()` values i.e. `Object.hashCode()` so they are different objects unless I'm missing something.  I'm running a Sun JDK 1.6.0_26.  Thanks for the `read` correction.

Comment: @Michael, what values from read are you expecting?  Because of buffering and packet data chopping you are not going to get a full 1024 read each time.  `read` does not block until it has an entire buffer's worth.  If you are trying to send an "entity" across then I'd recommend using serialization and writing and reading an object.  Otherwise you are going to have to do your own buffer maintenance with a `BufferedInputStream`, etc..

Comment: @Gray I am ok with any positive value from `read()`, as I just add that value to the total amount(`value`) that has already been read(`bytesRead`). Then when `bytesRead` becomes the value I am expecting from the server, `run` ends. I have just confirmed that the client is indeed throwing this "Operation timed out" exception before it has read all the data from the server. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @Gray Your code looks to be pretty much exactly what I have aside from mine running several concurrent connections. (I assign each server its own welcome socket to listen on). Still it throws exceptions probably half the times I run it. 

Here is my entire project: http://pastebin.com/wWeQXFGT
Server - main server spawns TransmissionWorkers to send data
Client - main client spawns StreamWorkers to receive from Transmission workers

Comment: @Gray can't explain that, but as flush() does nothing, your suggestion, while good practice, still won't help.

Comment: @EJP I was not suggesting `flush()` I was just converting his code to use a local variable for the stream.

Comment: @EJP, I've verified from my source at least that you get a `new SocketOutputStream(this)` from `PlainSocketImpl` every time you call `getOutputStream()`.  Maybe this will still work but it's a bad practice at the very least.

Comment: @Gray In which version? I've seen the source of every JDK major version there is since 1997 and I have never seen that. It has a member variable which is set lazily and returned on every call. And if you're not suggesting that flush() does anything, why would the change you suggested have any actual effect?

Comment: As I said @EJP, Sun JDK 1.6.0_26.  I also it might "worK" but wrapping a new `OutputStream` every time through the loop is at best tremendously bad form.  I'm done with this discussion.  Best of luck.